# Does multithreaded tokio run task on a single OS thread?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

When I spawn a task in tokio multithreaded runtime is it guaranteed that it will pick one of the runtime OS threads and run on it only? Or it might jump between different OS threads when polling futures?

*UPDATE*: If a task can switch between OS threads can it be configured to use only one thread?

Comment: @isaactfa Please read my question carefully.

Comment: My bad, the answer is still no. Futures may get passed between threads.

Comment: https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/index.html#current-thread-scheduler

Comment: "Work stealing" will bump it between threads.

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple facilities to handle task to thread mapping in Tokio:

1. A runtime can use multiple threads -- the default -- or a single thread.
2. Tasks can be spawned that may be executed on any of the runtime threads, or can be pinned to the current runtime thread.
3. Tasks can be spawned on dedicated threads, outside the normal runtime pool.

Follow-on for more details!

##### Runtime

Tokio has 2 runtimes: a multi-threaded one, which uses work-stealing for optimal efficiency, and a single-threaded one.

You can select the runtime either manually, using the [`runtime::Builder`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Builder.html):

```rust
let runtime = runtime::Builder::{new_multi_thread, new_current_thread}().build()?;
```

Or you can use the attribute macro [`main`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/attr.main.html):

```rust
//  Default, ie multi-threaded.
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> ... { ... }

//  Explicit multi-threaded, you can also configure the number of worker-threads.
#[tokio::main(flavor = "multi_thread", worker_threads = N)]
async fn main() -> ... { ... }

//  Single-threaded.
#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() -> ... { ... }
```

##### Task spawning

You can decide on an individual task basis where to run it:

- [`spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn.html) will use the current runtime worker threads pool.
- [`spawn_local`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_local.html) will use the current thread.
- [`spawn_blocking`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html) will use a newly created thread, reserved exclusively for this task.

Both `spawn` and `spawn_blocking` require the task and its result to be `Send`, as they involve (potential) thread migration, while `spawn_local` has no such requirement.

##### Task migration

So, when does a task migrate from one thread to another? It mostly depends on how you spawn it:

- `spawn_local` never involves moving the task, nor its result.
- `spawn_blocking` always involves initially moving the task to another thread, and its result back, however the task is not moved during its execution.
- `spawn` *may* involve moving the task at any point during its lifetime, and moving its result back, *if* using a multi-threaded runtime with more than 1 worker thread.

And that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a task can switch between OS thread as tokio is using a work-stealing scheduler. This is why [tasks are required to be `Send`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn.html).

If you want to stay on the same thread, aside from changing the whole runtime as @isaactfa suggested (which has the disadvantage of not using all cores), you can use [`LocalSet`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.LocalSet.html) and [`spawn_local()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_local.html).

Answer (score 0):

### Current-Thread Scheduler

The [current-thread scheduler](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/index.html#current-thread-scheduler) provides a single-threaded future executor. All tasks will be created and executed on the current thread. This requires the `rt` feature flag.

```
use tokio::runtime;

let rt = runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
    .build()?;
```

To use the single-threaded runtime known as the current_thread runtime, the macro can be configured using

```
#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
```